# Spectral reflectance identification of types of iron rust

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy, metal

Based on the Wikipedia page about [rust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust), there are red and green types of rust that occur on iron.  Red rust is the reaction with oxygen and water and the green with chlorine (in oxygen poor environments).

I understand the chemical reactions that forms these types of rust, but in the Wikipedia article, it states that:

> Several forms of rust are distinguishable both visually and **by spectroscopy**

(bolding mine). Visually, it'd be pretty obvious (one is red, one is green); spectroscopy-wise, I would imagine it to be a similar story - but what aspect of the types of rust cause this difference - hence, the question:

**Are the spectral reflectence features that distinguish between the red and green rust types based on what the iron reacts with (oxygen/water or chlorine), or is it based on the type of iron present (Fe<sup>2+</sup> vs Fe<sup>3+</sup>)?**

*Full disclosure, I have a similar question on Open Data.SE [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/spectral-reflectance-data-for-iron-rust), but are asking for an explanation in terms of spectral reflectivity.*

Comment: If available, the best spectroscopic technique for iron is usually Mossbauer.